# Получить имя базы данных в SQL запросе

Tags: sql, база-данных, select

Есть две базы даннных
`dbname1` и `dbname2`
В них есть одинаковые таблицы `data`, я хочу одним запросом вывести их содержимое, но каждая запись должна быть помечена именем базы данных

```sql
select * from `dbname1`.`data`, `dbname2`.`data`
```

Как мне реализовать что-то вроде

```sql
select database(), * from `dbname1`.`data`, `dbname2`.`data`
```

Чтобы в итоге получать строки в формате

```
dbname1  | 1
dbname1  | 4
dbname1  | 8
dbname1  | 11
dbname2  | 3
dbname2  | 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Испоьзуйте `UNION`

```
select 'db1', t.*
from db1.t

union 

select 'db2', t.*
from db2.t
```

Comment: Тю ... Есть контакт